# Shorthand for creating object with same field

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const json = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: "HI"
}
```

Is there a way to just pass in `{a : 1}` to function?

```
var someReturn = aOnly({a : json.a});
```

I am not sure if destructuring/constructuring of ES6 solves this problem. I can't seem to find the right syntax after reading several ES6 destructuring example.

**EDIT**
Nothing is wrong with the code I am just asking if there is a syntax to just extract "a" only from JSON without redundantly doing

`{a : json.a }`

the implementation of aOnly function is not the focus here

Comment: In your example, what are you wanting someReturn to equal/ what do you want aOnly to return?

Comment: i mean... you've given one option. What's wrong with it? It's easy to read, clean, etc.

Comment: @KevinB nothing is wrong : ) Just curious is there is ES6 syntax to shorten the extraction of `{a  : json.a}`

Comment: `const {a} = json;aOnly({a});` but... that's no shorter than what you're doing currently, and isn't as easy to read imo. (unless you're already benefitting from destructuring `json` elsewhere)

Comment: @KevinB thanks! I just posted the answer myself. I know what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: JSON and JavaScript objects are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I have figured out the right syntax. The initial mistake I was doing was trying to construct directly using `{ json.a }`, hoping that this will automatically turn into `{ a : json.a}` but the right way is do destruct first and construct later.

```js
var json = {
    a : "ASDF",
    b : 123,
    c : "Test"
 };
 
const {a, b, c} = json; // destructing

var aObject = aOnly({a}); // constructing
var bObject = bOnly({b});
var cObject = cOnly({c});

console.log (aObject);
console.log (bObject);
console.log (cObject);

function aOnly(a) { return a; }
function bOnly(b) { return b; }
function cOnly(c) { return c; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 object destructuring on object passed as parameter to pick specific property.

```js
const json = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: "HI"
}

function aOnly({a}) {
  return a;
}

var someReturn = aOnly(json);
console.log(someReturn)
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to ask : P But instead of modifying `function aOnly(a) {` to `function aOnly({a}) {` is there a way to "construct" a only instead from the function call?

e.g `var someReturn = aOnly ({json.a})`
or something similar?